# Неправильное поведение микросервиса при обращении к другому

Tags: java, spring-boot, микросервисы, spring-cloud

У меня возникает проблема при общении одного микросервиса с другим. Есть два МС: `mscompany` и `msrefbook`.

МС mscompany содержит контроллер:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/company")
public class CompanyController {
    private final MessageFuncActions messageFuncActions;

    public CompanyController(MessageFuncActions messageFuncActions) {
        this.messageFuncActions = messageFuncActions;
    }

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public ResponseEntity<Company> add(@RequestBody Company company) {
        messageFuncActions.sendNewCompanyMessage(company.getRangid());

        messageFuncActions.getRefbookResponseSender().asFlux().subscribe(response -> {
            boolean found = response.getPayload();
            System.out.println("found: "+ found);
        });

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

А также сервис, который позволяет отправить сообщение в другой микросервис и получить от него ответ, который затем обрабатывается в контроллере:

```
@Service
@Getter
public class MessageFuncActions {
    //Для того чтобы считывать данные по требованию (а не постоянно). Создаем поток, откуда данные будут попадать в канал message spring cloud streams
    //Для отправки сообщений в другие микросервисы
    private Sinks.Many<Message<Long>> companyMessageSender = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer(Queues.SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE, false); //С типом Long

    //Для приема ответа из других микросервисов
    private Sinks.Many<Message<Boolean>> refbookResponseSender = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer(Queues.SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE, false); //С типом Boolean

    @Bean //Создаем внутреннюю шину или трубу куда добавляем сообщение. Сообщения из него дальше будут попадать в брокер сообщений
    public Supplier<Flux<Message<Long>>> newCompanyActionProduce() {
        return () -> companyMessageSender.asFlux(); //будет считывать данные из потока Flux как только туда что-то положат
    }

    //Отправка сообщения в мс refbook, для проверки есть ли в БД мс refbook запись с rangid
    //Здесь rangId - это ссылка на refbook.id из микросервиса mis-refbooks
    public void sendNewCompanyMessage(Long rangId) {
        //Добавление в слушатель нового сообщения
        getCompanyMessageSender().emitNext(MessageBuilder.withPayload(rangId).build(), Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.FAIL_FAST);
        System.out.println("Сообщение отправлено: " + rangId);
        System.out.println(MessageBuilder.withPayload(rangId).build().getPayload());
    }

    //Получение ответа от мс refbook. Этот метод вызывается далее в контроллере
    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<Boolean>> newCompanyResponseConsume() {
        return booleanMessage -> {
            boolean found = booleanMessage.getPayload();
            System.out.println("Запись " + (found ? "найдена" : "не найдена") + " в справочнике");
            getRefbookResponseSender().emitNext(MessageBuilder.withPayload(found).build(), Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.FAIL_FAST);
        };
    }
}
```

Второй МС msrefbook также содержит сервис, который принимает и отправляет обратно сообщения

```
@Service
@Getter
public class MessageFuncAction {
    private final RefbookService refbookService;

    //Для отправки сообщений в мс company
    private Sinks.Many<Message<Boolean>> responseSender = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer(Queues.SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE, false);

    public MessageFuncAction(RefbookService refbookService) {
        this.refbookService = refbookService;
    }

    @Bean
    //Создаем внутреннюю шину или трубу куда добавляем сообщение. Сообщения из него дальше будут попадать в брокер сообщений
    public Supplier<Flux<Message<Boolean>>> newCompanyResponseProduce() {
        return () -> responseSender.asFlux();
    }

    //Проверяем есть ли в БД Refbook запись с полученным от мс company rangid и посылаем обратно ответ
    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<Long>> newCompanyActionConsume() {
        return longMessage -> {

            System.out.println(longMessage.getPayload());

            Optional<Refbook> refbookOptional = refbookService.findById(longMessage.getPayload());

            boolean found = refbookOptional.isPresent();

            if (found) {
                System.out.println(refbookOptional.get().getText());
            }

            System.out.println("Справочник с id :" + longMessage.getPayload() + (found ? " найден в БД" : " не найден в БД"));
            //getResponseSender().emitNext(MessageBuilder.withPayload(found).build(), Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.FAIL_FAST);
            getResponseSender().emitComplete(Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.FAIL_FAST);

        };
    }
}
```

Проблема в следующем: Во-первых если второй микросервис недоступен, то в контроллера mscompany все равно выводится `true`, как будто такой ответ получен из другого микросервиса, а во-вторых при каждом выполнении метода add в контроллере `found:true` выводится много раз, видимо все сообщения копятся и выводится каждый раз при вызове.

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно реализовать получение сообщения и как вывести сообщение если второй микросервис недоступен?

Пробовал переделать метод add таким образом:

```
@PostMapping("/add")
public ResponseEntity<Company> add(@RequestBody Company company) {

    CompletableFuture<Boolean> refbookResponseFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();

    messageFuncActions.sendNewCompanyMessage(company.getRangid());

    messageFuncActions.getRefbookResponseSender().asFlux().take(1).subscribe(
            response -> {
                boolean found = response.getPayload();
                System.out.println("found: " + found);
                refbookResponseFuture.complete(found);
            },
            error -> {
                System.out.println("Ошибка получения сообщения от мс refbook: " + error.getMessage());
                refbookResponseFuture.complete(false);
            },
            () -> {
                System.out.println("Таймаут: ответ от мс refbook не получен");
                refbookResponseFuture.complete(false);
            }
    );

    try {
        Boolean refbookResponse = refbookResponseFuture.get();
        System.out.println(refbookResponse + " получен");
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Но все равно при многократном вызове метода, даже если второй микросервис недоступен, все равно выводит `found:true`.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы обработать случай, когда второй микросервис недоступен, вам нужна механика тайм-аута. Вы можете использовать Mono с тайм-аутом и присоединить его к вашему CompletableFuture. Что-то вроде этого:

```
@PostMapping("/add")
public ResponseEntity<Company> add(@RequestBody Company company) {
    CompletableFuture<Boolean> refbookResponseFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
    // Устанавливаем тайм-аут для будущего ответа
    refbookResponseFuture.orTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    messageFuncActions.sendNewCompanyMessage(company.getRangid());

    messageFuncActions.getRefbookResponseSender().asFlux()
        .take(1)
        .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
        .subscribe(
            response -> { ... }, // То же самое
            error -> refbookResponseFuture.completeExceptionally(error),
            () -> refbookResponseFuture.complete(false)  // Ничего не найдено
        );

    try {
        Boolean refbookResponse = refbookResponseFuture.get();
        // ...
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        System.out.println("Timeout: ответ от msrefbook не получен");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.REQUEST_TIMEOUT);
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Чтобы исправить проблему с многократной обработкой сообщений, убедитесь, что вы подписываетесь на поток **Flux** таким образом, чтобы каждая подписка отслеживала только одно сообщение. Использование **take(1)** хорошо, но нужно также убедиться, что нет других случаев множественной подписки на одни и те же события.

Ваш метод **sendNewCompanyMessage** отправляет сообщение, но не ожидает ответа. Подписка в контроллере добавляется каждый раз при вызове метода **add**, и это может привести к многократной подписке на обработку одного и того же ответа. Вам может потребоваться механизм для сопоставления запроса с ответом, например, с использованием идентификатора корреляции.

Вы используете **emitComplete()** в своем сервере **msrefbook**, который успешно завершает поток и предотвращает получение любых других событий. Вы должны отправлять **emitNext** с сообщением о состоянии (найден или не найден), вместо того чтобы завершать поток.

Рассмотрите использование стратегии обработки ошибок для **Sinks.EmitFailureHandler** при отправке сообщений, чтобы обрабатывать неудачные попытки отправки и управлять backpressure.

Убедитесь, что в обоих микросервисах правильно настроены каналы Spring Cloud Stream для обмена сообщениями.

Чтобы корректно обработать случай недоступности **msrefbook**, добавьте тайм-ауты для ожидания ответа и используйте идентификатор корреляции для сопоставления запросов и ответов. Функционал комбинирования тайм-аута с **CompletableFuture** и **Flux** (как показано выше) должен помочь контролировать поведение в случае проблем связи с вторым микросервисом.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, буду у компьютера попробую сделать.

Comment: [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Comment: Пару вопросов осталось. В микросервисе вместо emitComplete у меня ранее было прописано getResponseSender().emitNext(MessageBuilder.withPayload(found).build(), Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.FAIL_FAST);, но когда микросервис получал сообщение вылетала ошибка которая говорила о том что longMessage.getPayload() невозможно привести с типу Long. Еще вопрос, при вызове метода sendNewCompanyMessage в нем же нужно подписаться на ответ или как у меня сделано можно создать новый метод с типом Consumer?

Comment: ошибки стиля "невозможно привести к типу Long" при обработке longMessage.getPayload() во втором микросервисе (msrefbook), проблема может быть в том, как сообщения сериализуются и десериализуются в системе обмена сообщениями (например, Kafka, RabbitMQ и т.д.). Убедитесь, что настройки сериализатора/десериализатора согласованы между микросервисами и что тип Long правильно поддерживается в обоих направлениях. Также проверьте, что конкретный брокер сообщений корректно работает с этим типом данных.

Comment: можете создать отдельный метод с типом Consumer, где вы будете ожидать и обрабатывать ответ, так как это позволяет логически разделять отправку запроса и обработку ответа.

Comment: В вашей текущей реализации после вызова sendNewCompanyMessage вы подписываетесь на поток refbookResponseSender в контроллере. Это работает, но подразумевает, что для каждого запроса вы создаёте новую подписку, что может приводить к утечке ресурсов, накоплению подписок и неожиданным повторным обработкам.

Comment: Чтобы улучшить этот процесс, вы можете реализовать модель запрос-ответ с использованием корреляции ID. Каждый запрос при отправке получает уникальный идентификатор (корреляционный ID), и при получении ответа вы проверяете, соответствует ли ID ответа ID запроса. Таким образом, вы всегда будете знать, какой ответ соответствует какому запросу. Это особенно важно, если система предполагает параллельную обработку и может обрабатывать несколько запросов одновременно.

Comment: Ваша текущая реализация, с использованием CompletableFuture, также может работать, если вы используете корреляционные ID и обрабатываете каждый ответ в отдельности, предотвращая многократную обработку одного и того же ответа.

Comment: Не могли бы подсказать где я могу подробнее прочитать о механизме корреляции? Только начинаю изучать взаимодействие микросервисов и то что я знаю это Supplier может что-то отправить, а Consumer принять это сообщение. Остальное пока неведомо мне.

Comment: Моя задача сейчас при вызове метода add отправить в другой микросервис сообщение с типом Long, чтобы второй микросервис проверил такую запись в БД и отправил обратно true или false, а в контроллере в зависимости от ответа выполнить действия.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/